# SQL Query: Most recent server entry, by server and disk

Tags: sql-server

I have a db that is storing server free disk space by disk every hour.

My query currently gets things in the following format:

```
Name        DriveSpace  Date        Time

Server1 F:  123123123   2016-02-24  07:00:00
Server2 F:  123123123   2016-02-24  07:00:00
Server3 F:  123123123   2016-02-24  07:00:00
Server1 G:  123123123   2016-02-24  07:00:00
Server2 G:  123123123   2016-02-24  07:00:00
Server3 G:  123123123   2016-02-24  07:00:00
Server1 H:  123123123   2016-02-24  07:00:00
Server2 H:  123123123   2016-02-24  07:00:00
Server3 H:  123123123   2016-02-24  07:00:00
Server1 F:  123123123   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server2 F:  123123123   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server3 F:  123123123   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server1 G:  123123123   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server2 G:  123123123   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server3 G:  123123123   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server1 H:  123123123   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server2 H:  123123123   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server3 H:  123123123   2016-02-24  12:00:00
```

I want to get the following:

```
Server1 F:  freespace   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server1 G:  freespace   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server1 H:  freespace   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server2 F:  freespace   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server2 G:  freespace   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server2 H:  freespace   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server3 F:  freespace   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server3 G:  freespace   2016-02-24  12:00:00
Server3 H:  freespace   2016-02-24  12:00:00
```

So basically:

I want the latest entry per disk, per server.
So all the latest updates on the disks of server 1, server 2 and server 3

Comment: simple GROUP BY with MAX on datetime col.

Comment: @jarlh Inclusion of that tag contradicts the advice given under that tag's description. Just sayin'.

Comment: What are the column names in the table?

Comment: @Mihai That's unlikely to work. He has multiple columns. If he just uses a `MAX(timestamp)` it could show the wrong freespace value for each server.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the columns were implied,I guess thats the succinct nature of comments.I didnt give an answer because those columns are ambigous,to say the least.

Comment: The columns were not clearly implied. The colon in the server name makes it look like freespace is part of the column, and the use the DriveFreeSpace and DriveSpace columns indicate other things we can't see that might throw this off.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I've made the question a bit more understandable :)

Comment: @Mihai I've made the question a bit more understandable :)

Comment: It looks like classic [greatest-n-per-group](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column names aren't clear, so I'm making them up. You should be able to infer real column names from my code:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM [Table] t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ServerName, MAX(Timestamp) TS,
    FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY ServerName
) t2 ON t2.ServerName = t1.ServerName and t2.TS = t1.TimeStamp
```

Or if it's somehow possible to have multiple records with the same server and timestamp:

```
WITH Keys As (
    SELECT ServerName, MAX(Timestamp) TS,
    FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY ServerName
)
SELECT v.*
FROM Keys t
CROSS APPLY (
     SELECT TOP 1 * 
     FROM [Table] u 
     WHERE u.ServerName = t.ServerName AND u.Timestamp = t.TS 
     ORDER BY FreeSpace
 ) v
```

Comment: First Query is working great, just not taking into account the Time. Only the date. So I get exactly what I wanted but not the most recent query by time, only the date (max date, can't get max time to work)

Comment: For the not taking the time into account... this looks like bad table design. The Date and Time values _should be part of the same column_, and that column should be a `datetime` or `datetime2` type.

Comment: That's true. After a bit of digging around, I found something that should work:
SELECT CAST(@Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(@Time AS DATETIME)

Thanks!